# next.js app works fine in local but returns 500 internal server error on production

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, next.js, internal-server-error

the problem i'm having is basically my app works fine in local but in production anywhere that i've used server side rendering returns 500 internal server error. the other parts of my site which are called normally like in `useEffect` or `componentDidMount` work completely fine, like my dashboard or authorization process works without a problem, but anywhere that i have used `ssr` returns 500.
Below is some examples of how i have handled my `ssr` pages.

index page:

```
import React from 'react';
import HomePage from '../components/homePage/index'
import { Api, GuestHeaders } from '../components/config'

const Home = (props) => {
  return <HomePage {...props} />
}

export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const Response = await Api.get(`/v1/index`, { headers: GuestHeaders })
  return {
    props: {
      Detail: Response.data,

    }
  }
}

export default Home
```

here is my `Api` component:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const GuestHeaders = {
    'Authorization': "",
    'content-type': 'application/json'
}

const Api = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'baseUrl'
})

export { Api, GuestHeaders };
```

here is my `server.js`:

```
// server.js
const { createServer } = require('http')
const { parse } = require('url')
const next = require('next')

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
const app = next({ dev })
const handle = app.getRequestHandler()

app.prepare().then(() => {
  createServer((req, res) => {
    // Be sure to pass `true` as the second argument to `url.parse`.
    // This tells it to parse the query portion of the URL.
    const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true)
    const { pathname, query } = parsedUrl


  }).listen(3000, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err
    console.log('> Ready on http://localhost:3000')
  })
})
```

and my `next.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    basePath: '',
    trailingSlash: false,
}
```

Comment: What do your server-side logs say?

Comment: i'm kinda new in nextjs and this is my first app, i don't know how to access it actually, you would really help me if you set me some pointers to how to access it.

Comment: Where do you [deploy](https://nextjs.org/docs/deployment) your app for production?

Comment: it's a cpanel and i followed the instructions of this article https://www.watfordconsulting.com/2021/02/08/deploy-next-js-applications-to-a-cpanel-web-host/

Comment: https://support.cpanel.net/hc/en-us/articles/360061635474-How-to-view-the-output-of-the-console-log-function-in-Node-JS-applications-that-are-deployed-though-cPanel-s-Application-Manager